# Which paths does Bower ignore by default?

Tags: bower

bower.json can specify which files should be ignored:

> `ignore` [array]: An array of paths not needed in production that you want Bower to ignore when installing your package.

Which paths are ignored by default?

Answer (score 2):

From the [source](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/v1.3.1/lib/commands/init.js#L289-L296):

```
json.ignore = mout.array.combine(json.ignore || [], [
    '**/.*',
    'node_modules',
    'bower_components',
    config.directory,
    'test',
    'tests'
]);
```

Apparently all dotfiles are ignored, as are the `bower_components`, `node_modules`, `test`, and `tests` directories. I don't know what `config.directory` is.

**Update:** I just published a package, and the `test` directory was *not* ignored. Apparently I've misunderstood the source code. I'd love clarification from a Bower contributor.

Comment: From the looks of it, up to 1.8.0, nothing is ignored by default. Starting with 1.8.0, the defaults DO apply. Just bit me in the ass after I upgraded a machine to 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Files which are listed in ignore property will not be installed by bower.

So, if you have a this kind of structure:

```
style.css
index.html
bower.json
script.js
```

and a bower.json file:

```
{
  "ignore": [ "./script.js" ]
}
```

**script.js** will not be installed within this component.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing which files Bower ignores by default. Does Bower ignore files in the __.git__ directory, for example? Where are these special paths listed?